# Monitor.TryEnter Advice

Tags: .net, multithreading

We are using Parallel Extensions in one part of our vb.net app to retrieve an datatable from a dictonary(of string, datatable).  In the method to retrive the table, we are using Monitor.TryEnter. Sometimes, we get the error "Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code." Here is what our method looks like:

```
        Try
           if Monitor.TryEnter(_ProductCollection, 200) = true then
              _ProductCollection.TryGetValue(name, ReturnValue)
            end if
        Finally
            Monitor.Exit(_ProductCollection)
        End Try
```

Should I try to implement a loop to make sure we obtain the lock, before trying to exit it? I am thinking the error is being thrown because I am trying to do the monitor.exit even if the monitor.tryenter is false.

Comment: Dictionaries support reading from multiple threads at a time, so maybe you don't even need the Monitor calls (if you're potentially writing at the same time, then you do need it, and you need to protect the writes with the same synchronization calls).

Comment: yeah, we are reading and writing at the same time. the code above is very similar to the write function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is being thrown from the `Monitor.Exit` call. What is happening is that `TryEnter` timesout occasionally and the lock is not acquired, but `Monitor.Exit` is always called since it is the `finally` block. That is the problem.  Here is how you can fix it.

```
Dim acquired As Boolean = False
Try
  acquired = Monitor.TryEnter(_ProductionCollection, 200)
  If acquired Then
    ' Do your stuff here.
  End If
Finally
  If acquired Then
    Monitor.Exit(_ProductionCollection)
  End If
End Try
```

Comment: You can save yourself the `Boolean` if you do the `Try`/`Finally` inside an `If Monitor.TryEnter(...)` section like the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/4tssbxcw.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) for `Monitor.TryEnter` shows.

Comment: @JeffBridgman: True. However, I specifically chose the structure here because it can be easily hardened against asynchronous exceptions via constrained execution regions with a simple call to `RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions` before the `Try` keyword. Admittedly that would be a pretty esoteric thing to do though.